# How do you define constantname for #IfDEF (VS 2010)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, constants, conditional-compilation

I want to add conditions to show certain layout/theme based on build, for example:

I want to define a constant for 2 apps (both debug and release)

```
#IFDEF APP1.Debug   
   --- display layout 1
#IFDEF APP1.Release
   --- display layout 2
#IFDEF  APP2.Debug
   --- display layout 3
#IFDEF  APP2.Release
   --- display layout 4
#ELSE
  --- display layout 5
#ENDIF
```

How do setup the constant names (above) in Visual Studio 2010? How do they show up under DEBUG and RElease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work under MSVC:

```
#if __PROJECT__  == "App1"
  #ifdef _DEBUG
    #define LAYOUT Value1
  #else
    #define LAYOUT Value2
  #endif
#elif __PROJECT__ == "App2"
  #ifdef _DEBUG
    #define LAYOUT Value3
  #else
    #define LAYOUT Value4
  #endif
#else
  #define LAYOUT Value5
#endif
```

Comment: Is there a require setup in Visual studio? How does the #if or #ifdef know what App2, App1 or layout means?

Comment: Yes, you will need to fill in your own values. This is just an example.

Comment: Do you need to add something using configuration manager to define values above? Is __Project already defined?

Comment: Yes, with visual c++ `__PROJECT__` will be defined and `_DEBUG` is added to the preprocessor definitions for the default debug configurations. If you have custom debug configs you will want to update the project properties to define it for them.

Comment: It looks like I may have been partially wrong. `__PROJECT__` does not seem to be defined in newer versions of VC. If it is not for you, you will need to create your own definition in your project properties.